# is there clear Example of Android ksoap2 returning array of objects from .Net Web service?

Tags: android, .net, service, web, ksoap2

I spent a time trying and debugging errors in this issue due to lack of specific info, I followed this [article](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html?showComment=1364980939179#c853038181979931664).

But this guy provide code snippets only, not a fully working sample.

Any clear working sample (android 4+) for returning and parsing array of objects from .Net Web service?

Answer (score 0):

I think that tutorial is sufficiently clear. But still you are searching another example check this: [How to parse the SOAP response with complex objects in Android](http://www.oguzozkeroglu.com/android-webservisten-donen-ic-ice-yapidaki-xmlin-parse-edilmesi/).

And do not forget to add `envelope.dotNet = true;` line to your code if your webservice is a .net service.

Its from my blog and its language is Turkish but you can easily understand the Java codes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code but i used this in java webservice not .net try and see

```
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "getNames");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = newSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        Vector xx = (Vector)  envelope.getResponse();
        final int size=xx.size();
        System.out.println("Size "+xx.size());
        List<Category> list=new ArrayList<Category>();
        for(int i=0;i<xx.size();i++){
            SoapObject soapObject=(SoapObject)xx.get(i);

            String categoryid=soapObject.getPropertyAsString("category");
            String name=soapObject.getPropertyAsString("name");
            String desc=soapObject.getPropertyAsString("description");

            int id=Integer.parseInt(categoryid);
            list.add(new Category(id,name,desc));

            System.out.println("CategoryId: " +categoryid + " Name: " + name + " Description " + desc);
        }
```