# Android calling webservice issue

Tags: android, web-services

i am calling webservice in this way..

```
public static String POST(String url, ArrayList<ModelLatLog> list,Context con){
 InputStream inputStream = null;
 String result = "";
 AppLog.logString(TAG+"URL     : "+url);
 AppLog.logString(TAG+"ListSize: "+list.size());

 try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    String json = "[";
    for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){            
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("DId", ""+list.get(j).get_idDevice());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Lat", ""+list.get(j).getLat());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Long", ""+list.get(j).getLong());
        jsonObject.accumulate("DIn", ""+list.get(j).getDt());
        jsonObject.accumulate("TIn", ""+list.get(j).getTm());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Dce", ""+list.get(j).getDce());
        if(j==0 ){
            json = json+""+jsonObject.toString();
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"if j: "+j);
        }
        else{
            json = json+","+jsonObject.toString();
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"else j: "+j);
        }
    }
    json = json+"]";
    AppLog.logString(TAG+"JSON: "+json);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    int resopnceStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    AppLog.logString(TAG+"set data resopnceStatus: "+resopnceStatus);
    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    if(inputStream != null)
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    else
        result = "Did not work!";

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    AppLog.logString("InputStream"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
return result;
}
```

AppLog is nothing it's log.d

it's giving me error like

```
11-19 18:15:39.088: I/Service(32261): Utility: set data resopnceStatus: 500
11-19 18:15:39.096: I/Service(32261): result: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the webservice is returning you an error, so the HTTP POST call actually worked.

Are you sending it the correct format? looks like its expecting XML request and you send JSON.

Comment: yes i had send correct formate u can chek tha i had parse in json and send

Comment: The webservice is returning you an error about the XML format, so the HTTP POST request worked obviously.

Comment: ya it's it's working but can you tell me as it's return me tag something like soap then this is soap webserice? becuse this webservce devloper also dont knot which service it's called

Comment: You asked about an Android code and got an answer. We have no way of debugging this webservice for you..   please mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are Taking so burden...
Just use volley service...It will take care of every thing...

Just use **StringRequest** in Volley..your task will be easy...
Download [volley](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples) example here

Comment: Cannot found library file of volley

Comment: Import that project into your workspace...In libs folder it will be there

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already figure out your problem, I believe ksoap2 is more intuitive for dealing with webservices on android, this link has a good example on it.

[is there clear Example of Android ksoap2 returning array of objects from .Net Web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783716/is-there-clear-example-of-android-ksoap2-returning-array-of-objects-from-net-we)

Comment: @ksude i am sending data to server

Comment: Oh I've actually been trying to figure out saving data to my days base mysrlf... I think you can still do it through ksoap.